# When using command to add user to json Bot gives error

Tags: discord.py

my bot keeps giving me this error when doing this command here is the error and code:

error:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/me/Desktop/Personal Coding/War bot/main.py", line 73, in on_message
    await level_up(users, message.author, message)
  File "/Users/me/Desktop/Personal Coding/War bot/main.py", line 47, in level_up
    lvl_start=users[f'{user.id}']['level']
KeyError: 'level'
```

code:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os
import json
import random
client = commands.Bot(intents = intents, command_prefix="-", case_insensitive=True)

async def on_ready():
    print('Bot is Online {0.user}'.format(client))
    print("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
    game = discord.Game("use prefix '-'")
    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.dnd,activity=game)


async def update_data(users, user):
  if not f'{user.id}' in users:
    users[f'{user.id}']={}
    users[f'{user.id}']['exp']=0
    users[f'{user.id}']['levels']=0
async def add_experience(users, user, exp):
  users[f'{user.id}']['exp']+=exp
  

async def level_up(users, user, message):
  with open ('levels.json','r') as g:
     levels=json.load(g)
  exp=users[f'{user.id}']['exp']
  lvl_start=users[f'{user.id}']['level']
  lvl_end=int(exp ** (1/4))
  if lvl_start<lvl_end:
    await message.channel.send(f'{user.mention} has levelled up! **LEVEL -{lvl_end}')
    users[f'{user.id}']['level'] = lvl_end
    
@client.command
async def start_levels(member):
  with open ('users.json','r') as f:
    users=json.load(f)
    await update_data(users, member)  
  with open ('users.json','w') as f:
    json.dump(users,f,indent=4)
  
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author.bot==False:
    with open ('users.json','r') as f:
      users=json.load(f)
      await update_data(users, message.author)
      await add_experience(users, message.author, 5)
      await level_up(users, message.author, message)
    with open ('users.json', 'r') as f:
      json.dump(users,f,indent=4)
  await client.process_commands(message)


@client.command()
async def mylevel(ctx, member:discord.Member=None):
  if member==None:
    member=ctx.author()
  id=member.id
  with open ('users.json', 'r') as f:
    users=json.load(f)
  lvl=users[str(id)]['level']
await ctx.send(f'{member.mention} is on level **{lvl}**')
```

I do not know the reason and I am very new to python and the discord api and the docs don't really make sense to me.

What I am expecting this code to do is add me towards to json. The command I tried was -start_levels

Answer (score 0):

First of all please check your indentation also you are missing `()` at the end of `@client.command`.

According to the error message here is your issue

`lvl_start=users[f'{user.id}']['level']`

The error says you have no such thing as `level` as indicated by `KeyError: 'level'`

When you defined the the JSON you used `levels` not `level`

so replace this inside `update_data(users, user)`

```py
users[f'{user.id}']['level']=0
```

P.S: Why are you using an f string it is not needed when you are only placing a variabule without ant text

Comment: Thanks for the answer it removed that error but gave a new one,


Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/me/Desktop/Personal Coding/War bot/main.py", line 75, in on_message
    json.dump(users,f,indent=4)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py", line 180, in dump
    fp.write(chunk)
io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable